# JNLP Applet loading on Safari or Firefox 3.6

Tags: java, safari, applet, jnlp, next-generation-plugin

I'm trying to load an applet using JNLP. Things work fine on every browser I've tested, except for Safari (tried on Safari 5.0.3 on OSX Snow Leopard).

This seems a Safari related bug, because even the JNLP applet used for testing in the [plugin2 page on Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/plugin2-142482.html#EXPERIMENTAL_FUNCTIONALITY) doesn't seem to be working, as Safari tries to load "Ignored.class" instead of looking at JNLP file.

Does anyone know a workaround for this issue?

Comment: The linked page is now here:  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/plugin2-142482.html#EXPERIMENTAL_FUNCTIONALITY

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question (and also added the answer :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after a lot of tinkering, it seems that the reason for this behavior lies in the plugins installed on Safari (and Firefox 3.6, it seems).

Instead of working with the latest Java Plugin 2 NPAPI, it's using some older plugin. So the real fix is to remove that older plugin from Safari: Go to `/Library/Internet Plug-ins` and remove `JavaPluginCocoa.bundle` (also, remove it if you have it on `~/Library/Internet Plug-Ins`).

This are the same directions described in this [Apple Knowledge Base article](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2834), although for different reasons.

When you do this, Safari will use the new Java Plugin 2, and will work exactly as other browsers using the newer plugin (namely, Chrome or Firefox 4, unsure about Opera. For Firefox 3.6 you'll have to do a similar thing, but following the steps in [this bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=631242))